# SqlDependency vs constant polling of a SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sqldependency, query-notifications

I am currently working on an email application where I have to monitor the table for any new record inserts and send email notification for each row. 
Right now the changes (inserts) will be at low rate but eventually it will become more.

Initially I was thinking about using a SQL Server job to query every 3-5 mins and then I looked into the `SqlDependency` but I am not sure whether SQL dependency / query notification will be the correct option for my requirement.

If there's an insert every minute then I will be polling the table every 1 min vs every 3-5 mins. I understand using `SqlDependency` I can get the notification instantly and send email notifications but I don't want that to become a performance impact by polling very often. Eventually there will be 10K inserts within a minute and not sure about the congestion between the other job and this `SqlDependency`.

I am thinking about going with the SQL Server job polling at certain predefined intervals. Any thoughts or suggestions? I am pretty sure someone should have faced the same situation before. Appreciate your feedback. Thanks

One more question
During peak periods it's Ok to poll the table every one minute or so after query notification but what happens to the records that gets inserted during the processing (select/send emails/update). I am assuming it will not get notified until next record gets inserted correct?

Comment: Why not a After Insert trigger?

Comment: It may be useful to compare the differences between using a Message Queue or using the database.  Not to say this is your solution, but you may be able to see if this is a better fit.  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/231410/why-database-as-queue-so-bad

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We already discussed about that and trigger is not an option.

Comment: this is a comment and not even an attempt to answer. email messages are not guaranteed to be delivered, may be delayed for days, can be delivered out of sequence so you may be notified of record 15023 before record 25 and if you get 10k insert in a minute to notify you will likely kill your email server or be banned from your isp's one. what about digest email sent one or twice a day?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. these are individual emails sent to users for different reasons so there is no option for digest email one or twice a day.